# jquery, text extraction

Tags: jquery

I have some string like this "asdf_0934_1234 - Pokemons".

How can I extract the strings asdf , 0934 , 1234 and Pokemons? Please note that this is just a sample since the texts can be other characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If everything will be separated by underscores and dashes, then:

```
var str = "asdf_0934_1234 - Pokemons";
var strings = str.split(/_|-/);
```

Then you probably want to trim leading and trailing spaces:

```
strings = $.map(strings, function (s) {
    return $.trim(s);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript `split` function. Here is the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

In your example:

`s = asdf_0934_1234 - Pokemons`

I'd first split by the `-` character:

```
s.split('-')
```

to get `Pokemons` and `asdf_0934_1234` 
and then split the second part again by the `_` delimiter to obtain everything you need.

After that, some of the strings might have leading or trailing spaces. So if you have all your results in one array, called `tokens`, you can get rid of that using:

```
$.map(tokens, function (s) {
    return $.trim(s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is of the same format every time, you could use multiple string splits.

```
str = str.split(" - ");
```

This will return an array.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp